# How to save one value of Parse object without overwriting entire object?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have two users accessing the same object. If userA saves without first fetching the object to refresh their version, data that userB has already successfully saved would be overwritten. Is there any way(perhaps cloud code?) to access and update one, and only one, data value of a PFObject?

I was thinking about pushing the save out to the cloud, refreshing the object once it gets there, updating the value in the cloud, and then saving it back. However that's a pain and still not without it's faults.

Answer (score 0):

This seems easy enough, but to me was more difficult than it should have been.  Intuitively, you should be able to filter out the fields you don't want in `beforeSave`.  Indeed, this was the advice given in several posts on Parse.com.  In my experience though, it would actually treat the filtering as deletions.

My goal was a bit different - I was trying to filter out a few fields and not only save a few fields, but translating to your context, you could try querying the existing matching record, and override the new object.  You can't abort via response.failure(), and I don't know what would happen if you immediately save the existing record with the field of interest and null out the request.object property - you could experiment on your own with that:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Foo", function(request, response) {

  // check for master key if client is not end user etc (and option you may not need)
  if (!request.master) {

    var query = new Parse.Query("Foo");
    query.get(request.object.id).then(function(existing) {
      exiting.set("some_field", request.object.get("some_field"));
      request.object = exiting; // haven't tried this, otherwise, set all fields from existing to new
      response.success();
    }, function(error) {
      response.success();
    });
  }
});
```